# При ссылке на сайт, соцсети подставляют любые картинки только не те что в статье

Tags: html, соцсети

Создал сайт. Если ссылку на статью с этого сайта выставить в Facebook или Однокласниках, то Facebook/Однокласники для заставки в посте использует картинку не из статьи, а из других статей типа *"Читайте также то и то..."*, почему так?

Уже замучался переписывать код, казалось бы в `html` документе картинка статьи - первая, а соцсети лезут за картинками дальше, к мелким картинкам, хотя они ниже в `html` документе, и к заставке подставляют совсем не то что в статье. Как заставить соцсети отображать страницу правильно в постах?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В целом, все очень хорошо [документировано](http://ogp.me/) и известно.  Нужно подсунуть правильную картинку в meta тег.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.site.ua/url/to/my/picture.png" />
```

Протестировать свою страницу (а иногда и ошибку найти), можно в [Facebook opengraph debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

Из известных "особенностей" фейсбука:

- картинку выбираются в порядке следования в тексте, а картинка с og:image в самом верху.
- картинку может пропустить, если она "маленькая" (вроде меньше 200 пикселей)
- картинку может пропустить, если url содержит пробелы или кириллицу.

Comment: Есть еще гайды по размерам, которые позволяют повысить качество репостов: http://www.likeni.ru/events/Infografika-SHpargalka-po-razmeram-graficheskikh-elementov-v-sotsialnykh-setyakh/

Answer (score 0):

Использовать [Open Graph](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/open-graph/intro-open-graph.xml) разметку. За изображение будет отвечать `og:image`.